# How to align my Instagram feed in footer?

Tags: html, css

I had a website http://kunalparashar.com/kanishkabuildcon/index.php please visit the footer and help me align the Instagram widget what should I add to the CSS...

```
<div class="bottom">
    <ul>
        <li id="instaFeed-footer"></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/stevenschobert/instafeed.js@2.0.0rc1/src/instafeed.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var userFeed = new Instafeed({
                limit: 3,
                sortBy: 'most-liked',     
                get: 'user',
                target: "instaFeed-footer",
                resolution: 'standard_resolution',
                template: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" id="{{id}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
                });
                userFeed.run();
</script>
```

Comment: In official docs the target is a `div` not a list item `li`: `<div id="instaFeed-footer"></div>`

Comment: You could try `<div class="bottom" style="margin: 0px auto;">`